# Quest for a SMD power connector

Tags: connector, surface-mount, automotive

I am looking for something similar to [this connector](https://www.elpro.org/gb/stelvio-kontek-cpm508-series/39347-cpm508-6.html), in SMD form.

Any hints?

Comment: Looks like a clone of the Phoenix Contact COMBICON series. (made by many others too). I've only seen it in thru hole. Due to the relatively large size, and non-trivial insertion/removal forces, I think they're a more mechanically robust compared to SMT, but I bet they make something like it.

Comment: these have quite a high insertion force. you're likely to rip the traces off the PCB when plugging or unplugging.